# android app crash with the log like this

Tags: android, crash

I have face a  crash, but the log did not contain useful information. Even report some wrong with jacoco. I use jacoco to generate unit test report in my gradle file.

```
D/SystemAdController( 1395): Package:com.miui.home is not in the list
D/SystemAdController( 1395): requestSplashScreen duration:0
I/ActivityManager( 1116): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.HOME] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.miui.home/.launcher.Launcher} from pid 11837
W/System.err(11837): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /jacoco.exec: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)
W/System.err(11837): at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:409)
W/System.err(11837): at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:88)
W/System.err(11837): at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_773e439.output.FileOutput.openFile(FileOutput.java:67)
W/System.err(11837): at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_773e439.output.FileOutput.writeExecutionData(FileOutput.java:53)
W/System.err(11837): at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_773e439.Agent.shutdown(Agent.java:137)
W/System.err(11837): at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_773e439.Agent$1.run(Agent.java:54)
W/System.err(11837): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)
W/System.err(11837): at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
W/System.err(11837): at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
W/System.err(11837): at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:393)
W/System.err(11837): ... 5 more
I/AndroidRuntime(11837): VM exiting with result code 0, cleanup skipped.
I/AudioFlinger(  271): setAppName(), name=[system_server], active=[0]
W/InputDispatcher( 1116): channel '438b8700 com.myapp.hch.my/com.myapp.hch.my.library.app.home.controller.MainActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
E/InputDispatcher( 1116): channel '438b8700 com.myapp.hch.my/com.myapp.hch.my.library.app.home.controller.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
D/dalvikvm( 1116): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2033K, 24% free 27211K/35516K, paused 86ms, total 86ms
I/dalvikvm-heap( 1116): Grow heap (frag case) to 36.162MB for 1637776-byte allocation
D/baidu_location_service( 6578): baidu location service stop ...
W/InputDispatcher( 1116): Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel '438b8700 com.myapp.hch.my/com.myapp.hch.my.library.app.home.controller.MainActivity (server)'
I/ActivityManager( 1116): Process com.myapp.hch.my (pid 11837) has died.
```

Comment: Please, add your code to post.

Comment: I am so sorry,but I can not find out  where the problem is. so I don't know which code section should I post. There is no code call org.jacoco.agent

Answer (score 1):

W/System.err(11837): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /jacoco.exec: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)

NO access right to the file system. May you try another location or check the I/O permission?

Comment: But in my code, I did not use check the  jacoco file path.I just config jacoco in my gradle file